# Give all files a .jpg extension

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory and some of the files' extensions are in uppercase (.JPG) instead of lowercase.

I want to make sure every file has .jpg as its extension. How would I do this from a shell prompt?

Comment: It's a shame that linux doesn't have AppleScript.

Comment: Its so great that Linux has no AppleScript.

Answer (score 15):

Using [***Shell Parameter Expansion***](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for f in *.JPG; do
    mv "${f}" "${f%%.JPG}.jpg"
done
```

The `"` characters will take care of filenames containing spaces, as photographs often do.

Comment: +1 This solution works even if you have spaces in the filename, but you mean "$f" instead of "f".

Comment: Shell Parameter Expansion is a bit cryptic, one could use basename instead: for f in *.JPG; do mv "$f" "\`basename $f .JPG\`.jpg"; done

Comment: @math: I prefer my version as it works with filenames containing whitespace and will also work with `/path/to/*.JPG`. You're welcome to submit your own answer, of course :)

Comment: Of course basename will strip of leading directories but will work with spaces inside filenames. (I don't think this is worth of an answer ;) so I posted it as a comment)

Answer (score 10):

If you can use external tools (not only bash), check `rename` command!

```
rename .JPG .jpg *
```

The `rename` is part of `util-linux`.

Comment: rename is... problematic. There's a version of rename that comes with `perl` that accepts different arguments to do the same thing.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Which version BTW?

Answer (score 3):

If you do have spaces in filenames:

```
for f in *.JPG; do [[ -f "${f}" ]] && mv "${f}" "${f/%JPG/jpg}"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to have a look at the `mmv` command. It's suited exactly for this kind of tasks. In your scenario it would be:

```
#> mmv "*.JPG" "#1.jpg"
```

The [man page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) is full of examples, so it takes no time to get used to it.

On [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) systems it can be installed with:

```
#> aptitude install mmv
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have spaces in the filenames:

```
for f in *.JPG; do mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/JPG$/jpg/'`; done
```

Comment: It'd be easy enough to make this work for files with spaces in the name: just add double quotes around both arguments to `mv`.

Comment: I don't have spaces. What do I add to make this happen in the CURRENT directory. At the moment I get error - mv: cannot stat `*.JPG': No such file or directory

Comment: you don't have any JPGs there.